# A game on a regular (2n+1)-agon

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-geometry

A and B play a game on a $(2n+1)$-agon where $n\ge 1, n\in\mathbb{N}$

They draw diagonals such that every diagonal drawn

i) Cannot be previously drawn

ii) only intersect an EVEN number of drawn diagonals (if two diagonals share the same vertex it doesn't count in version 1, counts in version 2)

The player who has no legal move loses. Who has the winning strategy?

For $n=2$ A wins in version 1 and 2. For $n=3$ it's quite complicated to bash. My prediction is that A wants to prevent B from copying them, so A plays $v_1$ to $v_n$. Then the case bash is quite annoying

Comment: Are the sides allowed to be drawn?  It sounds like yes but usually they are not counted as diagonals.  Maybe you should just say that a player connects two vertices.

Comment: This is an interesting question; where is it from?

Comment: Sides are not allowed to be drawn. This came from Pranav Sriram's book Olympiad Combinatorics. The way the question was worded was not very clear.

Comment: can you explain what is the version 1 and version 2 and how the diagonals are counted if they share a vertex? Does sharing a vertex counts as an intersection?

Comment: V1: Sharing a vertex doesn't count as an intersection.

Comment: V2: Sharing a vertex does